# why Custom CSS won't work alongside Bootstrap 5

Tags: html, jquery-ui, css-selectors, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-5

I have used **bootstrap 5** to design a dashboard. For designing a dashboard I needed a custom css style beside ***bootstrap***.
But the **problem** is my custom css won't work unless I put **!important** in front every single line of code.
***So*** the **Question** is:
Is there any solution to use less '**!important**' keyword or any other solution not to use the **!important** keyword.[the custome css code illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vu7Qo.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways ( recommend doing it both )you can easily override a frameworks' css rule is:

1. [CSS Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) Which is basically being more specific by adding more selectors. Basically, IDs > classes > general tags, but you can read more about it in the link.
2. The other way is the order in which you import your style sheets in your . You should put your custom css AFTER the bootstrap or any other css.

```css
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="custom_style.css">
</head>
```

Comment: Thanks, The first option worked for me.   I tried the second one before, but it didn't work.